# How to run Android app with old version of Google Play Services library?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have the legacy application which actively use `"com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient"` but in the new GooglePlayServices version there is no such class!! https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html *"...If you were previously using `LocationClient`, call the APIs in the `com.google.android.gms.location` package instead..."* said there.

As I understand there is no option to force an old version of Google Play Services with custom application on the device, am I wrong?
 Does it mean that I should rewrite some portion of application? 
Is there any method to run app with old version of Google Play Services library on the device?

Answer (score 0):

All Google Play Services are backward compatible - as long as you compile with Google Play Services 6.1 or below, you can continue to use `LocationClient`.

However, that does mean you will not get any of the new APIs, performance improvements, or other features available only in the newer versions of Google Play services so you should definitely consider moving over to the new API as soon as possible.

Comment: I have latest version of Google Play Services (seems 6.5, version "6587000") and prepare a library from it. I can not see that class in jar and got: " error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
  symbol:   class LocationClient
  location: package com.google.android.gms.location" 
when trying to compile an application...

Comment: Yes, the new version of Google Play Services doesn't have `LocationClient` - like I said, you need to use the older version. If you are using Gradle, this is easy, but Eclipse makes this very tricky.

Comment: Well I am using NetBeans (and sometimes command line) , I have no idea where to get old Google Play Services . If only I had 6.1 ... Also what about users? As I understood they will always have 6.5 on their devices as said here https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html : "... Devices running Android 2.3 or higher that have the Google Play Store app will automatically receive updates to Google Play services. Enhance your app with the most recent version of Google Play services without worrying about your users' Android version...."

Comment: MY DEVICE HAS 6.5.99 and I had never updated it manually... Why should I use 6.1? library it seems useless... Please clarify me about GooglePlay Services version policy.

Comment: Every devices gets the new version of the Google Play Services **app**. The newer versions of the **app** work with **all** versions of the library you include in your app - that's how apps built with older versions of the library continue to work, even after the **app** is updated. Unfortunately, Google only makes previous versions of Google Play Services (and every other library they provide) easily accessible from Gradle, which would require you to move to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) which is probably more work than moving to the new APIs.